# Set limit to button select

Tags: php, jquery, html

**This code have 3 box, by clicked will change to red, how to limit only three of them can be select?**

**At the fourth one may show a notification or alert to users.**

**i need keep several select option to make the each of the button have different animation**

So i need keep the select 1 to 4.
Thanks for reading and helping.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button.change").click(function() {
    $("button.change.selected");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  });
  $(".button1.change").click(function() {
    $("button1.change.selected1");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected1");
  });

  $(".button2.change").click(function() {
    $("button1.change.selected2");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected2");
  });

  $(".button3.change").click(function() {
    $("button1.change.selected3");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected3");
  });

});



function descriptionComputer() {
  var x = document.getElementById("ComputerDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description computer";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}

function descriptionCalculus() {
  var x = document.getElementById("CalculusDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description calculus";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}

function descriptionPeridoicl() {
  var x = document.getElementById("PeridoiclDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description peridoicl";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}

function descriptionNone() {
  var x = document.getElementById("NoneDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description None";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}
```

```css
.button {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button1 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button2 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button3 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
}

.selected1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.selected2 {
  background-color: black;
}

.selected3 {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="descriptionComputer()" class="button change"></button>
<div id="ComputerDIV"> </div>

<br><br>

<button class="button1 change" onclick="descriptionCalculus()"></button>
<div id="CalculusDIV"> </div>

<br><br>
<button class="button2 change" onclick="descriptionPeridoicl()"></button>
<div id="PeridoiclDIV"> </div>

<br><br>
<button class="button3 change" onclick="descriptionNone()"></button>

<div id="NoneDIV"> </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Y**ou can start from here .. with just one click event for all buttons `.button` class .. no need to use more classes .. so change all buttons to be `button` class .. then you can use `if($(".button.change.selected").length < 3){` to check the selected buttons

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button.change").click(function() {
   var ThisEl = $(this);
   if($(".button.change.selected").length < 3  || ThisEl.hasClass('selected')){  // if less than 3 buttons selected
    ThisEl.toggleClass("selected");  // toggle the selected class
   }else{  // if over than 3
    console.log('you can select just 3');
   }
  });
});



function descriptionComputer() {
  var x = document.getElementById("ComputerDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description computer";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}

function descriptionCalculus() {
  var x = document.getElementById("CalculusDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description calculus";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}

function descriptionPeridoicl() {
  var x = document.getElementById("PeridoiclDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description peridoicl";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}

function descriptionNone() {
  var x = document.getElementById("NoneDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description None";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}
```

```css
.button {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button1 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button2 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button3 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="descriptionComputer()" class="button change"></button>
<div id="ComputerDIV"> </div>

<br><br>

<button class="button change" onclick="descriptionCalculus()"></button>
<div id="CalculusDIV"> </div>

<br><br>
<button class="button change" onclick="descriptionPeridoicl()"></button>
<div id="PeridoiclDIV"> </div>

<br><br>
<button class="button change" onclick="descriptionNone()"></button>

<div id="NoneDIV"> </div>
```

**Note:** if you need to make it your way with more classes 1,2,3 you can use `data-` attribute instead to control each button action separately

> Don't forget to change button1,button2,button3 classes to button

And while personally I don't like to combine inline click with jquery click you can use the next code by using `data-` attribute with `.next('div')` to select the next div for the button instead of using `id` for each div

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button.change").click(function() {
   var ThisEl = $(this);
   var GetText = ThisEl.attr('data-text'); // get the text from data- attribute for this button
   var GetClass = ThisEl.attr('data-class'); // get the class from data- attribute for this button
   if($(".button.change.selected").length < 3 || ThisEl.hasClass('selected')){  // if less than 3 buttons selected
    ThisEl.toggleClass("selected "+ GetClass);  // toggle the selected class
    ThisEl.next('div').html(ThisEl.hasClass('selected') ? GetText : '');  // change the next div text
   }else{  // if over than 3
    console.log('you can select just 3');
   }
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button1 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button2 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button3 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.selected1 {
  background-color: red;
}
.selected2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.selected3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button change" data-text="description computer" data-class="selected1"></button>
<div> </div>

<br><br>

<button class="button change" data-text="description calculus" data-class="selected2"></button>
<div></div>

<br><br>
<button class="button change" data-text="description peridoicl" data-class="selected3"></button>
<div> </div>

<br><br>
<button class="button change" data-text="description None" data-class="selected1"></button>

<div> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but these buttons have different animation and background to achieve, so button1,2 ,3 ,4 still can change to button? So i need to keep the buttons and the select1, 2,3,4.

Comment: @bohan answer updated .. check the 2nd snippet on my answer .. as I said you can use `data-` attribute to change the action for each button

Comment: Thanks for help, i will try about your answer. Do you have some suggest for beginner to learn Jquery. Like some website or YouTube channel?

Comment: @bohan this one where I learned  from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNb8T5NBdQg&list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810  its from 2011  .. also you can check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3nrLc_JOF7k&list=PLillGF-RfqbYJVXBgZ_nA7FTAAEpp_IAc    .. don't worry about 200 video in the playlist its a short videos .. good luck and have a great day :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. i have try your code, but the Jquery links(src=" ??? ") looks not right. That could not run in my PC.

Comment: @bohan ok [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNb8T5NBdQg&list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810) and [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3nrLc_JOF7k&list=PLillGF-RfqbYJVXBgZ_nA7FTAAEpp_IAc)

Answer (score 1):

**Try Following** in Which I edited your code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var ClickedButtonCount=0;
  $(".button").click(function() {
  debugger
  if(ClickedButtonCount<3)
  {
  if($(this).hasClass('selected'))
  {
    ClickedButtonCount--;
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
  }
  else if(ClickedButtonCount>=0)
  {
  ClickedButtonCount++;
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  }    
  }
  else
  {
  if($(this).hasClass('selected'))
  {
    ClickedButtonCount--;
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
  }
  else
  {
  alert('you can select Only 3 Box')
  }
  }
  });
});



function descriptionComputer() {
  var x = document.getElementById("ComputerDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description computer";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}

function descriptionCalculus() {
  var x = document.getElementById("CalculusDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description calculus";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}

function descriptionPeridoicl() {
  var x = document.getElementById("PeridoiclDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description peridoicl";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}

function descriptionNone() {
  var x = document.getElementById("NoneDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description None";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}
```

```css
.button {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button1 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button2 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button3 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="descriptionComputer()" class="button"></button>
<div id="ComputerDIV"> </div>

<br><br>

<button class="button" onclick="descriptionCalculus()"></button>
<div id="CalculusDIV"> </div>

<br><br>
<button class="button" onclick="descriptionPeridoicl()"></button>
<div id="PeridoiclDIV"> </div>

<br><br>
<button class="button" onclick="descriptionNone()"></button>

<div id="NoneDIV"> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i need keep the selected1 to 4 to set the different animation for the each of button select.

Comment: ok then call saperate event on each class & write the condition of selecting max 3 box

Comment: sorry i am new to the Jquery could you help me change in code?

Comment: Check New answare which I posted

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following Code**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var ClickedButtonCount=0;
  $(".button.change").click(function() {
  debugger
   if(!ValidateSelectedCount($(this),'selected'))
   {
    if($(this).hasClass('selected'))
      {
      $("button.change.selected");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
descriptionComputer();
      }
      else
      {
      alert('you can select 3 box')
      }   
   }
   else
   {
   $("button.change.selected");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
descriptionComputer();
   }   
  });
  $(".button1.change").click(function() {
    if(!ValidateSelectedCount($(this),'selected1'))
   {
   if($(this).hasClass('selected1'))
      {
      $("button1.change.selected1");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected1");
    descriptionCalculus();
      }
      else
      {
      alert('you can select 3 box')
      }   
   }
   else
   {
   $("button1.change.selected1");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected1");
   descriptionCalculus();
   }    
  });

  $(".button2.change").click(function() {
     if(!ValidateSelectedCount($(this),'selected2'))
   {
   if($(this).hasClass('selected2'))
      {
      $("button2.change.selected2");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected2");
   descriptionPeridoicl();
      }
      else
      {
      alert('you can select 3 box')
      }   
   }
   else
   {
   $("button2.change.selected2");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected2");
    descriptionPeridoicl();
   }    
  });

  $(".button3.change").click(function() {
     if(!ValidateSelectedCount($(this),'selected3'))
   {
   if($(this).hasClass('selected3'))
      {
      $("button3.change.selected3");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected3");
    descriptionNone();
      }
      else
      {
      alert('you can select 3 box')
      }   
   }
   else
   {
   $("button3.change.selected3");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected3");
    descriptionNone();
   }    
  });
  
  function ValidateSelectedCount(Event,ClassName)
  {
     if(ClickedButtonCount<3)
    {
      if($(Event).hasClass(ClassName))
      {
      ClickedButtonCount--;
      }
      else if(ClickedButtonCount>=0)
      {
      ClickedButtonCount++;
      } 
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      if($(Event).hasClass(ClassName))
      {
      ClickedButtonCount--;
      }
      else
      {
      return false;      
      }
    }
  }

});



function descriptionComputer() {
  var x = document.getElementById("ComputerDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description computer";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}

function descriptionCalculus() {
  var x = document.getElementById("CalculusDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description calculus";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}

function descriptionPeridoicl() {
  var x = document.getElementById("PeridoiclDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description peridoicl";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}

function descriptionNone() {
  var x = document.getElementById("NoneDIV");
  if (x.innerHTML === " ") {
    x.innerHTML = "description None";
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}
```

```css
.button {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button1 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button2 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button3 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
}

.selected1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.selected2 {
  background-color: black;
}

.selected3 {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button change"></button>
<div id="ComputerDIV"> </div>

<br><br>

<button class="button1 change"></button>
<div id="CalculusDIV"> </div>

<br><br>
<button class="button2 change"></button>
<div id="PeridoiclDIV"> </div>

<br><br>
<button class="button3 change"></button>

<div id="NoneDIV"> </div>
```